# Microsoft Graph query for get all user and also groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am new working on Microsoft graph API.I have search box in which I am searching users .But when I am writing group name then  it's not working. Can anyone help me what's exact query for getting user as well as group email.

bellow is my query

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQFwL.png)

Comment: Copy-paste the code into the question. A screen reader reads it as "my query enter image description here", so it won't help much. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You said "get all user and also groups". Do you mean list groups and the user members of groups?

Comment: @PamelaPeng i want list of  all users and all groups in one query.

Answer (score 0):

There is the code to list users. The `header` could be removed and `GetAsync()` is required in your issue.

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Select(u => new {
        u.mail // mail is the SMTP address for the user.
    })
    .Filter("startsWith(mail,'xxx')")
    .GetAsync();
```

If you want to get all users and all the groups that the user is a member of, you can add `.Expand("memberOf")` in C#.

Comment: Thanks of your Answer but it not fulfill my problems. i want list of  all users and groups in a one query. i want users +groups in a list.

Comment: There is no graph API to list users +groups in a single query.